# What are the situations for changing Janeu?

Tags: rituals, yagnopavitam

While janeu must be changed if not covered on ear during shouch, but what about situations like wet dreams or other unprecented actions? And what is the samadhan if done so?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: By shouch, do you mean defecation?

Comment: Yes, @SeverusSnape that is implied, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Upon researching the Peeths of legitimate Guru Shishya tradition, I have come across 1008•guru who is current acharya under Shankaracharya of Jyotirpeeth and Badrinath, who has answered this question.

Wet dreams occur at a state of unconsciousness as a result, that is forgiven and the person must immediately take a bath, since the intention to break Brahmacharya was not there.

Other situations include not covering right ear with janeu while doing shouch, dirtying the sacred thread. It must be periodically changed after 4 months regardless. However sandhyavandanam must be done daily even if done once in a day ( ideally thrice), if not done for a week the man loses the authority to wear janeu.

There are many videos on Youtube for changning janeu, one is Karmakand by Anandpathak that I refer.

For sandhyavandanam, please ask the Brahmin which Veda his sampraday follows, mine is Yajurveda so I perform the Mantras which relate to Yajurvediya Sandhyavandanam.

Shukla Yajurveda is valid for everyone, please refer Nityakriya Puja Prakashan by Gita Press.

I have answered this for other fellow Hindus with similar doubt.

Jai Shree Ram.